# Power Bi, data structure Radar chart

Tags: powerbi

I had like to display data using a Radar Chart. It has to be done without changing data structure too much, too keep the possibility to use filters afterwards. My data comes from Excel and organised under columns as follow:

Customer | Turnover | market share | Coverage

I figured out that the Chart works when data is normalised and organised under this form:

Customer | Criteria | value

Where Criteria is either "Turnover", "market share" or "Coverage"

The problem is I did it using steps on Excel data to get a suitable form, but it prevents me from analysing data.

How can I organise my data by using power bi queries only?

Comment: This may help: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Formatting-data-for-Radar-Charts/td-p/377721

Comment: Are you asking how do replicate the steps, which you did in Excel to get it in a suitable form, using just Power BI? If so, it would help to know what steps those were.